# uistackview is broken in uicollectionview

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uistackview

isShowText and isHideText are subviews of UIStackView.

isShowText is shown if data.isShow is true.
isHideText is shown if data.isHide is true.

There is an issue with uistackview breaking on some devices.

here is the code!

**CollectionViewCell code**

```
func initUI( _ data : Data){
    self.data = data

    if data.isShow {
        isShowText.isHidden = false
    }else {
        isShowText.isHidden = true
    }

    if data.isHide {
        isHideText.isHidden = false
    }else {
        isHideText?.isHidden = true
    }

    self.setNeedsDisplay()
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

---

uistackview is horizontal.

[image]

Comment: Please provide some screenshot for more clarification

Comment: @SidharthKhanna i added img! plz help me 

Comment: In your case, data.isShow and data.isHide are both true. Everything is good in your code. Can you share the screenshot of the stackview in your storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

in my case, i fixed with this code :)